# Adaptive Sampling not working in ApplicationInsights

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to get sampling working in AppInsights and not having much luck.  Here's my repro:

First, I setup a TelemetryClient:

```
TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
configuration.InstrumentationKey = "f7968b3b-b5ac-4e00-a6d9-f4915e5c5d32";
telemetryClientTest = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
var builder = configuration.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond: 1);
builder.Build();
```

Next, I try logging a bunch of events:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    telemetryClientTest.TrackEvent("SampledThingHappened");

     if(i % 100 == 0)
         await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Every hundred, I'll delay for a second.  What I expect is a few chunks of `SampledThingHappened` events, each with a itemCount of probably around 100 or so.  Instead, I see all 500 items each with an itemCount of 1.

```
customEvents
| where name == "SampledThingHappened"
| where itemCount > 1
```

returns no items.

Everything in the DefaultTelemetrySink looks correct, and I can see my AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor in there with all the correct settings:

[image]

Comment: which app insights package and which kind of project(web, console) are you using?

Comment: @IvanYang This is an ASP.NET Core project (console) using `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` package.  I'm currently running it on .NET Framework 4.8 but I'll try it on .NET Core in a sec and see if there's any diff..  I've done this before on .NET Core and it seemed to work..

Comment: @IvanYang Unfortunately, same behavior on .NET Core 3.1 (console app running Kestrel and ASP.NET Core)

Answer (score 3):

Since, there is no `ApplicationInsights.config` for ASP.NET Core applications, so all configuration is done via code. **Adaptive sampling is enabled by default for all ASP.NET Core applications. You can disable or customize the sampling behavior.**

**Customize Adaptive Sampling settings:**

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, TelemetryConfiguration configuration)
{
    var builder = configuration.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
    // For older versions of the Application Insights SDK, use the following line instead:
    // var builder = configuration.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;

    // Using adaptive sampling
    builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond:5);

    // Alternately, the following configures adaptive sampling with 5 items per second, and also excludes DependencyTelemetry from being subject to sampling.
    // builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond:5, excludedTypes: "Dependency");

    // If you have other telemetry processors:
    builder.Use((next) => new AnotherProcessor(next));
    
    builder.Build();

    // ...
}
```

*For ASP.NET application App Insights sampling setup, visit [Configuring adaptive sampling for ASP.NET applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#adaptive-sampling).*

To verify the actual sampling rate no matter where it has been applied, use an [Analytics query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview) such as below:

```
union requests,dependencies,pageViews,browserTimings,exceptions,traces
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| summarize RetainedPercentage = 100/avg(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h), itemType
```

If you see that `RetainedPercentage` for any type is less than 100, then that type of telemetry is being sampled.